# Rendering vue template in javascript's replace

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a block of text `Pigs __(cant)__ fly` . I've rendered input field by regex

```
str.replace(/\s__\(([ a-z0-9'&*%$#@!~`+ ]*)\)__\s/g, ` <input type="text" name="blanks" @click="helo"> `);
```

Is there a way to render vue template as a second param to replace? I tried SFC and called the component as the second param in replace and it rendered Objectobject.

Any idea how this can be done?

I am tyring to create a Fill in the blanks with vuejs

Comment: You want `Vue.compile`

Comment: Either `Vue.compile` or look into a different approach for your issue. Sounds like you've made something that could be solved in a cleaner way by using only Vue, then again I know too little about your application to know why you did what you did.

Comment: @SimonHyll can you suggest other ways than mine??

Comment: Again, don't know your app well enough to know exactly what it is you're doing, but based on "fill in the blanks" I'd say a solution with `v-if` and `v-for` in a regular Vue template would be the "normal" Vue manner of doing it.